# locally finite closed coverings are fundamental

Tags: general-topology

First of all the definitions, since i'm not english and I don't know if it's clear what I'm talking about. Let's take a topological space $X$

A covering is locally finite if for every $x \in X$, there is a neighbourhood $I_x$ of $x$ that intersects only a finite amount of sets of the covering. The situation I am proposing is about a locally finite covering whose elements are closed sets.

A covering is called fundamental if for every set $\Omega$ in $X$, we have that $\Omega$ is open iff $\Omega \cap A_i$ is open in $A_i$ for every $i\in I$, where $\{A_i \}_{i\in I}$ is the fundamental covering.

I think this theorem is quite simple, because it was proven in a first course of topology. To be precise, it was first proven that every finite closed covering (that is a finite covering composed of closed sets) is fundamental, and then this result was used to prove this stronger version (every finite closed covering is locally finite).

The question is: how can I use the fact that every finite closed covering is fundamental to prove that every locally finite closed covering is fundamental as well?

The problem is that I don't get the proof, cause when he says like "this is open" and "this is closed" I can't understand where he is working, and how I can deduce that if a set is (for example) open in a subset, then it is open in the whole topological space. I know how to conclude that if the subspace is open itself, but I can't see how to apply that here

Comment: Your "question" could use some improvement. First, there is no question, so I'm not sure what kind of answer to give. Can you formulate an actual question? Second, you write "...this stronger version...", but you don't say what the stronger version is.

Comment: @LeeMosher Edited, tell me if it's clear now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cover $A_i, i \in I$ of $X$ is also fundamental iff

> A subset $A$ of $X$ is closed iff $A \cap A_i$ is closed in $A_i$ for each $i$.

The proof is obvious.

Also:

> A locally finite family of closed sets $B_i, i \in I ,B_i \subseteq X$ has a closed union $B = \cup_i B_i$ (note that this is an axiom for finite unions).

For suppose $p \in \overline{B}, p \notin B$. As the family is locally finite, there is an neighbourhood $U$ of $p$ such that $I_0 = \{i: U \cap B_i \neq \emptyset \}$ is finite. But then $B_0 = \cup \{B_i: i \in I_0\}$ is closed, as a finite union of closed set, and then $U \setminus B_0$ is a neighbourhood of $p$ that misses all $B_i$, contradicting that $p \in \overline{B}$. So indeed $B$ is closed.

Now to see locally finite closed covers are fundamental: take $A \subseteq X$.
If $B$ is closed, all $A \cap B_i$ are closed in $B_i$ by definition of the subspace topology. If however all $B_i \cap A$ are closed in $B_i$ all sets $A_i = B_i \cap A$ are closed in $X$ by a standard fact, and then $A_i, i \in I$ is a locally finite family (as the larger $B_i$ already is locally finite) and its union $\bigcup_i A_i = \bigcup_i (A \cap B_i) = A \cap (\bigcup B_i) = A \cap X= A$ is closed by the above fact. This shows $B_i, i \in I$ is fundamental.

Comment: Thank you very much. I only have two questions. First, the first proof is obvious because you just have to take the complement set of the definition with open sets, right? The other one is: who is $O$?

Comment: Indeed for the first one. The second I meant $U$, the witnessing nbhd for local finiteness.